# Subtracting a group of rows to another group?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this.

```
stage   val A       temp    shape
stage_0 10  red     hot     square  
stage_1 11  red     hot     square  
stage_2 12  red     hot     square  
stage_0 10  red     temp1   square  
stage_1 11  red     temp1   square  
stage_2 12  red     temp1   square  
stage_0 10  red     temp2   square  
stage_1 11  red     temp2   square  
stage_2 12  red     temp2   square  
stage_0 10  blue    temp1   square  
stage_1 11  blue    temp1   square  
stage_2 12  green   temp1   square  
stage_0 10  blue    temp2   square  
stage_1 11  blue    temp2   square  
stage_2 12  green   temp2   square
```

Column A has three unique values, temp has 4 and shape has 3. Each of the combination of this unique values has three stages with different values. In total, my dataframe has 108 rows.

I would need to subtract the section of the dataframe where `(A == 'red') & (temp == 'hot') & (shape == 'square')` to the other combinations in the dataframe with the same value for temp. So stage_0 of this combination should be subtracted to stage_0 and so forth, of another combination where
`temp == 'temp1'` and `(A == 'red') & (shape == 'square')`.

The differences will be a new column. Is there a way to do this without creating new dataframes?

The result will be like this for `(A == 'red') & (shape == 'square')`. Will also have to do this for all combinations of A and square.

```
stage   val A       temp    shape    out
stage_0 10  red     hot     square   0  
stage_1 11  red     hot     square   0
stage_2 12  red     hot     square   0
stage_0 11  red     temp1   square   1
stage_1 12  red     temp1   square   1
stage_2 13  red     temp1   square   1
stage_0 14  red     temp2   square   4
stage_1 15  red     temp2   square   4
stage_2 16  red     temp2   square   4
stage_0 10  blue    temp1   square   10
stage_1 11  blue    temp1   square   11
stage_2 12  green   temp1   square   12
stage_0 10  blue    temp2   square   10
stage_1 11  blue    temp2   square   11
stage_2 12  green   temp2   square   12
```

Comment: Can you provide code to generate a complete input? What shape do you expect for the output?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the below answer to:

```
query = "(A == 'red') & (temp == 'hot') & (shape == 'square')"

ref = df.query(query1)

out = (
 df.merge(ref[['stage', 'A', 'val', 'shape']],
          on=['stage', 'A', 'shape'],
          suffixes=(None, '_ref'), how='left')
   .assign(out=lambda d: d['val'].sub(d['val_ref'], fill_value=0))
)
```

Output:

```
      stage  val      A   temp   shape   out  val_ref
0   stage_0   10    red    hot  square   0.0     10.0
1   stage_1   11    red    hot  square   0.0     11.0
2   stage_2   12    red    hot  square   0.0     12.0
3   stage_0   11    red  temp1  square   1.0     10.0
4   stage_1   12    red  temp1  square   1.0     11.0
5   stage_2   13    red  temp1  square   1.0     12.0
6   stage_0   14    red  temp2  square   4.0     10.0
7   stage_1   15    red  temp2  square   4.0     11.0
8   stage_2   16    red  temp2  square   4.0     12.0
9   stage_0   10   blue  temp1  square  10.0      NaN
10  stage_1   11   blue  temp1  square  11.0      NaN
11  stage_2   12  green  temp1  square  12.0      NaN
12  stage_0   10   blue  temp2  square  10.0      NaN
13  stage_1   11   blue  temp2  square  11.0      NaN
14  stage_2   12  green  temp2  square  12.0      NaN
```

###### older answer

Setting up a dummy example:

```
from itertools import product

vals = {'stage': ['stage_0', 'stage_1', 'stage_2'],
        'A': ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
        'temp': ['hot', 'temp2', 'temp3', 'temp4'],
        'shape': ['square', 'shape2', 'shape3']
       }

df = (pd.DataFrame(product(*vals.values()), columns=list(vals))
        .assign(val=lambda d: range(1, len(d)+1))
     )

df.shape
# (108, 5)
```

Now you can query your condition, and the rest of the rows (you can use several methods here). Then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on stage and compute your difference:

```
query = "(A == 'red') & (temp == 'hot') & (shape == 'square')"

ref = df.query(query)

out = (
 df.drop(ref.index)
   .merge(ref, on='stage', suffixes=(None, '_ref'))
   .assign(out=lambda d: d['val']-d['val_ref'])
)
```

Output:

```
       stage      A   temp   shape  val A_ref temp_ref shape_ref  val_ref  out
0    stage_0    red    hot  shape2    2   red      hot    square        1    1
1    stage_0    red    hot  shape3    3   red      hot    square        1    2
2    stage_0    red  temp2  square    4   red      hot    square        1    3
3    stage_0    red  temp2  shape2    5   red      hot    square        1    4
4    stage_0    red  temp2  shape3    6   red      hot    square        1    5
..       ...    ...    ...     ...  ...   ...      ...       ...      ...  ...
100  stage_2  green  temp3  shape2  104   red      hot    square       73   31
101  stage_2  green  temp3  shape3  105   red      hot    square       73   32
102  stage_2  green  temp4  square  106   red      hot    square       73   33
103  stage_2  green  temp4  shape2  107   red      hot    square       73   34
104  stage_2  green  temp4  shape3  108   red      hot    square       73   35

[105 rows x 10 columns]
```

If you only want the new column, [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
out = df.drop(ref.index)
out['out'] = out['val']-out['stage'].map(ref.set_index('stage')['val'])
```

Output:

```
       stage      A   temp   shape  val  out
1    stage_0    red    hot  shape2    2    1
2    stage_0    red    hot  shape3    3    2
3    stage_0    red  temp2  square    4    3
4    stage_0    red  temp2  shape2    5    4
5    stage_0    red  temp2  shape3    6    5
..       ...    ...    ...     ...  ...  ...
103  stage_2  green  temp3  shape2  104   31
104  stage_2  green  temp3  shape3  105   32
105  stage_2  green  temp4  square  106   33
106  stage_2  green  temp4  shape2  107   34
107  stage_2  green  temp4  shape3  108   35

[105 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Hi! I've pharesed my question wrong. The values of A and shape should be the same and temp will be the only changing value. so one set of combination will be subtracted to four sets only.

Comment: @noobiejp then you can adapt my answer, see the update